Principle of condensation of singularities: Non-meagerness of singularity set
Let $X$ be a Banach space, $\{Y_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ a collection of normed spaces and $T_n^m: X \rightarrow Y_m$ a collection of bounded linear operators. Suppose that for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a $u_m \in X$ such that $\limsup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ||T_n^m(u_m)|| = \infty$.
Prove that the set $A = \{u \in X: \limsup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ||T_n^m(u)|| = \infty, \forall m \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is nonmeager in $X$ (that is, $A$ is not a countable union of nowhere-dense sets).
I already managed to prove $A$ is non-empty (By contradiction and using the Banach-Steinhaus theorem) but I'm at a loss on how to proceed to show it is nonmeager. I'm trying to do it by contradiction, assume it's meager and pick $u \in A$ then $u$ is in a nowhere-dense set, but can't see how that leads to a contradiction.
Any help/hints are appreciated.

Should your set $A$ be
\begin{equation}
A = {u\in X : \limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |T_{n}^{m}(u)| = \infty ; \text{for all} ; m\in\mathbb{N} }
\end{equation}
instead of what you currently have? Otherwise you would have $A = X$ and the statement would be obvious since $X$ is a Banach space.

Yes, I'll correct the question

Note that you can write the complement of $A$ as
\begin{align*}
X\setminus A &= \bigcup_{m\in\mathbb{N}} \{ u\in X : \limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \|T_{n}^{m}(u)\| < \infty \} \\
&= \bigcup_{m,k\in\mathbb{N}} \{ u\in X : \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \|T_{n}^{m}(u)\| \leq k \}. \tag{$\ast$}
\end{align*}
It can be shown that each set in the countable union ($\ast $) is a closed set with empty interior. Each such set is closed by continuity. Furthermore, each such set has empty interior because otherwise by a scaling argument
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \|T_{n}^{m}(u)\| < \infty \tag{$\ast \ast$}
\end{equation}
would hold for each $u\in X$. In particular, ($\ast\ast$) would hold for $u_{m}$ which is a contradiction.
As a result, $X\setminus A$ is meager set. If $A$ was also meager then $X = (X\setminus A) \cup A$ would be meager. But $X$ is a Banach space so this is impossible by the Baire category theorem. Therefore $A$ is nonmeager.

I guess in this case I don't need to argue that A is nonempty first right? It's covered by the meagerness of the complement that it cannot be.

That's correct. The empty set is meager so $A$ can't be the empty set.
